# CAN SAID ME THE ERROR FOR CREATE MY USER?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE USER LUIS IDENTIFIED BY BDT02
DEFAULT TABLESPACE CURSOS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE CURSOS
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON CURSOS
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English only site. However, there is [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Show us the error message you get!

Comment: This is a problem: DEFAULT TABLESPACE CURSOS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE CURSOS. The Default Tablespace is where your user will create their tables and store data. The Temporary Tablespace is where they will execute sorts. These **cannot be the same table** because those are different types of tablespace. If you don't know the name of your Temporary Tablespace (it is usually called TEMP but customs vary) just omit that clause and Oracle will assign you to the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

There are various issues that are mentioned in inline comments:

```
CREATE USER PEDRO IDENTIFIED BY /*USER*/ BDT02 -- REMOVED THIS user KEYWORD
DEFAULT TABLESPACE CURSOS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE CURSOS
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON CURSOS -- removed quota of 10M
```

Cheers!!

Comment: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges